# Connecting to a computer using Remote Desktop does not work first time

Tags: windows-xp, 64-bit, remote-desktop

I'm having a weird sort of problem with Remote desktop and that too, only on one machine.

If I boot up this machine, and then try to Remote desktop into it, it does not work.( I get the following error:

> The client could not connect to the
>   remote computer.
>
> Remote connections might not be
>   enabled or the computer might be too
>   busy to accept new connections.  It is
>   also possible that network problems
>   are preventing your connection.
>
> Please try connecting again later. If
>   the problem continues to occur,
>   contact your administrator.

)

But if I physically log into it & then log out, and then try to Remote desktop into it, it works flawlessly.

The problematic machine is Xp 64 Bit, but other systems with Xp 64 Bit work fine.

Any Ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

[This forum thread](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/windows-xp-enable-remote-desktop-before-logon-t647423.html#td_post_1986481) suggests disabling Fast User Switching, if that is feasible.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are a site for professionals and home users; would you be able to give directions for the users who are not familiar with disabling the Fast User switching?

Answer (score 0):

How soon after booting up the machine do you try to remote desktop into it?  You may be trying to access it before the terminal service starts.  The other possibility would be that you are trying to access it before it starts broadcasting it's name.  I would try to ping the machine after boot up to see if the second computer can resolve a name for it.  You may also want to modify the configuration of the network card to enable netbios over tcpip which can be found under advanced settings for tcpip.  I'm assuming you don't have a wins or active directory server in your environment?